# update table sql server fields maybe empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I want to update a database in my asp.net application. The updated fields are set in textboxs.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandText = "update dbo.User_Info SET FirstName=@FirstName, LastName=@LastName,Degree=@Degree,Organization=@Organization,Phone=@Phone,Ext=@Ext where UserName =@username";
cmd.Parameters.Add("FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextFirstName.Text;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextLastName.Text;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("Degree", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextDegree.Text;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("Organization", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextOrg.Text;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextPhone.Text;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("Ext", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextExt.Text;
```

However maybe some fields I don't want to update them at all. Just leave them as blank, so how to modify the code?
For example, suppose I just want to update FirstName, the command should be

```
cmd.CommandText = "update dbo.User_Info SET FirstName=@FirstName where UserName =@username";
```

However another guy just want to update "Degree", therefore the command will be:

```
cmd.CommandText = "update dbo.User_Info SET Degree=@Degree where UserName =@username";
```

Is there an universal command for considering various scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Universal?  I doubt it.  Some options:

Customize your UPDATE statements based on the inputs by dynamically adding the fields:

```
string sql = "update dbo.User_Info SET ";
if (TextFirstName.Text != null)
{
    sql += "FirstName=@FirstName, ";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextFirstName.Text;
}
// etc.
```

Change your SQL statement to check for NULL paramteres and leave the initial values if they are NULL:

```
// If @FirstName is NULL, "update" with the original value
cmd.CommandText = "update dbo.User_Info SET FirstName=COALESCE(@FirstName, FirstName)," 
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build you update query depending on the content of the controls? You could iterate them and use them only if they aren't empty, like this (crude example follows):

```
string query = "UPDATE User_Info SET ";
foreach (Control ctl in panel.Controls)
{
    if (ctl.Type == "Textbox")
    {
        query += ctl.Tag + " = " + "@" + ctl.Tag //assuming you preload the table names on the tags of the controls and you wanna name the parameters like that
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + ctl.Tag, ctl.Text);
        query += ", "
    }
 }
 //You need here something to eliminate the last comma
 query += "WHERE UserName =@username"
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", _usrName);
```

Something like that could work. Of course, instead of iterating you could always use a switch sentence.

Comment: `Control` doesn't have a `Type` property.  You can do `typeof(TextBox).Equals(ctl.GetType())`

Comment: Looks good, if there are other textboxs which are irrelevant to the query? How can I distinguish with them?

Comment: Don't set their tags. It's quick and dirty (not to mention highly difficult to maintain), but it works. Also, what Inuyasha said.